# supportedInterfaceOrientations not called with iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I searched for an answer to this, but couldn't find anything which solved my problem.

So here's the problem:
I have a custom UINavigationController, when creating it the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method is called on the rootViewController(only supports portrait).
But when pushing an other ViewController onto the stack this method isn't called on the pushed ViewController(supports all but upside-down).

I solved it by calling `[self supportedInterfaceOrientations]` in the `viewDidLoad`-method, but i think that's not a good way to solve the problem.

I hope you can help me in that matter.

Here's my code i implemented in the second viewController.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setGlobalOrientationMask:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown];
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else {
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setGlobalOrientationMask:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll];
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}
```

I think the solution from johnMa should work fine for the most apps, but in my case, there's a special problem i think, but i solved it by myself now(not sure if it's a good one, but it works).

I implemented the `- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated` method on my navigationController-delegate.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (DEF_SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7")) {
        if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)]) {
            [viewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this can help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should implement these code in your custom NavigationController.

```
 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if ([self.topViewController isMemberOfClass:[RootViewController class]]){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
   }  
 }
```

because when your device rotate, it will ask your app rootController(Custom NavigationController) first, if `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is not implement there. then it will ask the rootController for `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

> A view controller that acts as the root view controller of the main window or is presented full screen on the main window can declare what orientations it supports.[View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW1)

Comment: this helped, but there's 1 problem which occurs now when rotating from portrait to landscape, the first rotating calls supportedInterfaceOrientations on my navigationcontroller, but the rotation is not done, only when rotating it a second time to a landscape orientation the rotation is done correctly

Comment: did you find any solution to the first time/second time problem? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

this works fine in iOS 8.

but in iOS 9 (Xcode 7) i became a warning:
"Conflicting return type in implementation of 'supportedInterfaceOrientations': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')"

i have changed it to:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{  
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of the chosen answer:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if self.topViewController is ViewController {
        return .Portrait
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}
```