# Temporarily restrict app to specific orientation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an app that supports all orientation, but in certain cases I would like to temporarily restrict it to only portrait. It's not a mix of view controllers that need to be only portrait and those that can be any orientation, rather, I would like to disable orientation changes when the user clicks a button on screen, while the view controller stays the same.

When looking for ways to restrict UI orientation of a `UIViewController`, methods that pop up are `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()`. Both don't quite work for me:

- `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` runs only once when the view is loaded, so even if I make its return value conditional, it does not run after the condition changes.
- my view controllers are presented inside a navigation stack, not modally, so `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()` does not run at all.

Is there any way to achieve the effect I'm looking for?

Comment: When you say `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` runs only when the view is loaded, what do you mean? Can you elaborate on that point?

Comment: Meaning when the viewController is initialized and loaded, the method runs. Then a user taps a button and a flag is set to restrict the orientation. Then if I rotate the device, it rotates and I can see in the debugger that `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` was never ran again after that first time. Can I force the OS to refresh its data on supported orientations by calling the method again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume your view controllers are in a navigation controller. Without the navigation controller, `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` is called whenever the device is rotated. HOWEVER, when embedded in a navigation controller, the navigation controller decides whether the view controller should rotate. (See examples below)
[image]
[image]

What do you need to do? Implement supportedInterfaceOrientations() in a custom UINavigationController like so:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if self.topViewController is RootViewController {
        return .Portrait
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}
```

This is a duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088956/supportedinterfaceorientations-not-called-with-ios-7) but I didn't see a swift example. For whatever class you want to stay in portrait, just replace RootViewController with the class name.

Comment: Agh! That navigation controller! Gets me every time!

Comment: Apparently `UITabBarController` also has the same issue. Adding the same override to a custom `UITabBarController` solves this.

Comment: Definitely something that can easily be overlooked!